# Imroving my message

Tags: grammaticality

I am Mexican and my English is good, but there is a chance to make a mistake.

I am gonna leave city after living here for 20 years and moving to new city. I have made many friends and memories right here. So need to write a good and heart touching email to them. Please improve my message for any errors or anything. Make it a good one.

Message:

> Hey Guys, here i have to announce something that might be the most heart breaking message. It's a time to say goodbye to 'CITY NAME', a goodbye to you all, a goodbye to all memories that i created here. I got and lost many things here. I know most of the people doesn't find it hard to move from one city to another. It's common but for me it was the most tough step to take. I lost my beloved grandfather here.

Please experts help me in improving it. It doesn't sound so correct and deep. I need to write a memorable and good message. a touching one.

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic here, sorry. Please see the help section for what is and is not on-topic here. Good luck on your move!

Comment: any category for proof reading ?

Comment: No, we do not proof read. If you have friends who speak English well, maybe they can help you. We are happy to answer *specific* questions about the language, however, that are not readily answered by dictionaries, etc.

Comment: @medica I was unaware. Should I delete my response?

Comment: @njboot - you were kind enough to put effort into helping OP; I would let it be. :) If we do this for some, though, we may attract others who want the same service. In the future, while it's kindhearted, it's not a fit for this site. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @medica still a newbie! thanks for informing me. I'll abstain from doing so in the future. Regards :)

Comment: Also: turn on spell checking in your browser. It would have caught "imrovin" and your lower case personal pronouns

Comment: @medica I know this should be in meta but there is a _proofreading_ tag, which the OP used, but it has no information; wouldn't it make sense to edit that tag to say _"If your question involves proofreading then it is off-topic, do not ask the question as it will be closed as off-topic"_ ?

Comment: I am from the planet Anunarky. My human and machine language skills of this planet is very good because I monitor NSA. I am leaving planet A for planet B. Please check my C++ code and see if it correctly conveys my farewell message.

Comment: @Frank - I edited his question, removed all the tage (which were useless in this context) and subbed the proofreading tag, so it doesn't get pulled up as *grammar* or some other. Sorry for the confusion. I think that tag edit is great!

Answer (score 2):

> Hey guys, I've got some sad news to announce. After living here for 20
>   years, I've decided it's time to leave 'CITY NAME.' Though I'm saying
>   goodbye to you all, I'll never forget all the friends I've made and
>   the good times we've shared together. Though most people find it easy
>   to relocate, it's been a hard and emotionally taxing experience for
>   me. At the same time, I feel as though a fresh start is necessary and
>   it's time to move on.

Comment: if u could add more coherence ?

Comment: @user3518032 - Please, Sir, don't push your luck.

Comment: sorry :) i am new and need time to understand it completely